# how to fetch a notes and attachment of custom object and i want to send the notes title and body through of contact in accounts

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-email-service

i have already done some codes check the codes below and tel me what's wrong in this

```
public PageReference send()
{
  List<Contact> accounts=[SELECT Email,id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId ='001i000000g7erl'];
  List<Id> emailid=new list<Id>();  
  for(Contact mail: accounts)
    {
        emailid.add(mail.Id);

    }
     List<Brand__c> notes = [SELECT Name__c,(SELECT CreatedBy.Name,Title,Body FROM Notes)FROM Brand__c Where Id='a0di0000003EkAU'];
     List<String> note=new list<String>();
     for(Brand__C no:notes)
     {
         note.add(no.Id);
         note.add(no.Id);
     }

    //String[]address=new String[] {'note'};  
    Messaging.MassEmailMessage emails = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
    emails.setTargetObjectIds(emailid);
    emails.setTemplateId('00Xi0000000J9hx');
    emails.SaveAsActivity=(false);
    emails.setsubject('notes');
    emails.setBody(notes.Body);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {emails});
    return null;
}
}
```

my custom object name is brand and i want o fetch the notes and attachment of tat object 
in this code i have fetch the contact email and i want to fetch the notes and attachment title and body if in this code im getting error like this

Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 31 column 20
if any one know this pls help me in this

Comment: Which line in this method refers to line 31? There's less than 30 lines provided.

Comment: eamils.setBody(notes.Body) this is the line im getting error

Answer (score 1):

Your variable notes is a list of `Body__c` objects (containing one item only). Each entry in that list also has a list of Node objects in a variable called `Notes`. (See e.g. [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).)

So to loop over the zero or more notes you need something like this:

```
Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] emails = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {};
for (Note n : notes[0].Notes) {
    Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
    email.setBody(n.Body);
    ...
    emails.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```

You should probably rename your variables to make the code clearer.

**PS**

As it doesn't look like and values from `Brand__c` are used, the simpler solution is to just query the `Note` object directly like this:

```
Id brandId = 'a0di0000003EkAU';
for (Note n : [
        select CreatedBy.Name,Title,Body
        from Note
        where ParentId = :brandId
        ]) {
    ... 
}
```

A similar query can be done for `Attachment` too.

Comment: it doesnt work is showing error like variable doesnt exist

Comment: @user7538 You are best placed to figure out errors like that as you will also have been given a line number and you have the full current source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming of variables makes this code very confusing.

`email.setBody(notes.Body)`  notes is a `List<Brand__c>` so it won't have a `Body` field. You'll want to do `notes[0]` to get the Brand__c sObject, even then you're getting a list of `Note` objects as part of your `Brand__C` sObject so you'll need to either

1. Get the Body of the first Note  `notes[0].Notes[0].Body` <-- this assumes at least 1 Note was returned.
2. Loop through all the Notes that were returned and collect all the body information

l

```
String bodies = '';
for(Note n : notes[0].Notes){
    n.Body + ' \n ';
}
```

Also, you are only getting the Notes child object, your code does not get the Attachment child object.